# Exclude categories from category list of a product

Tags: category, product-page

I added categories unordered list on product page with the following code

```
<?php
        $currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
                             ->addIsActiveFilter();
                             foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
          echo '<li> <a href="'.$cat->getUrl().'" title="'.$cat->getName().' ">'.$cat->getName().'</a> </li>';
        }

        ?>
```

I use some "service" categories and for this I set "not included in menu and in category list"

Is it possible to hide this "special categories" from the product detail list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your filters:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', array('eq'=>1))
```

Comment: Consider adding full code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', array('eq'=>true))
        ->addIdFilter($currentCatIds)
        ->addIsActiveFilter();
?>
```

You will need to use `->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', array('eq'=>true))` which is default attribute filter function in Magento.

For `addIdFilter($currentCatIds)`, there is default function in category resource class.

**Class**: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection`

**Function**: `addIdFilter($categoryIds)`

**Param**: `array $categoryIds`

Comment: okay cool.. what is the difference between your answer and Taylor's ? Can you justify ?

Comment: Edited description in my answer